# When variables refer to the same object, how is that called, and why does python have this feature?

Tags: python, python-2.7, reference, pass-by-reference

In python, two different variables can represent the same object. Observe:

```
>>> list1=['This is list1.']
>>> list2=list1
>>> list2[0] = 'This is actually list2 not list one.'
>>> print list1
['This is actually list2 not list one.']
```

[Here is a link to this code.](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=list1%3D%5B%27This+is+list1.%27%5D%0Alist2%3Dlist1%0Alist2%5B0%5D+%3D+%27This+is+actually+list2+not+list+one.%27%0Aprint+list1&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=0http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=list1+=+%5B%27This+is+list1.%27%5D%0Alist2+=+list1%0Alist2%5B0%5D+=+%27This+is+actually+list2+not+list+one.%27%0Aprint+list1&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=0)
As you can see, there is no list1 or list2, just one list with two names. I am well aware of this effect, and I remember from a book that this is intentional, but I forget what the phenomenon is called. Also, it is occasional the source of bugs, and other languages do not have this problem. I do have a feeling that certain things having to do with objects would break though without it. What are the specific benefits of this (since python is all I really know.)

Comment: [Potentially useful](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=list1+%3D+%5B'This+is+list1.'%5D%0Alist2+%3D+list1%0Alist2%5B0%5D+%3D+'This+is+actually+list2+not+list+one.'%0Aprint+list1&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=0)

Comment: How would function arguments work if this wasn't the case?

Comment: Huh, maybe my book was wrong.

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: Python for Absolute Beginners, second edition

Comment: @Lattyware: in C++, objects are copied unless they are explicitly declared as references (or pointers, but then the pointers are copied). So it is possible to build a language that works differently.

Comment: @larsmans I was talking specifically to Python, as copying an object isn't trivial in Python.

Comment: @Lattyware: sure, but the OP is soliciting a comparison with other languages :)

Comment: @larsmans Indeed, I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 5):

This is usually called having multiple *references* to a single object. The number of references is called the [refcount](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount).

In the case of recursive data structures (trees, linked lists) it may also be called structure sharing.

> What are the specific benefits of this

That you don't have to copy a value to pass it to a function. Say you have a function

```
def print_list(l):
    print("I see %d elements:" % len(l))
    for x in l:
        print(x)
```

When you pass a list to this function, what is actually passed is only a reference to the list rather than a copy of the list's contents. Similarly, methods like `append`, `extend`, `sort` etc. are hard to implement without this feature; they'd have to construct and return new lists all the time. The same goes for any function or method that changes a data structure in-place.

When you're doing multithreaded programming, sharing of data structures is in fact a common way of setting up communications: multiple threads would reference a common [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) that they use to pass messages around.

> other languages do not have this problem

In all languages, except purely functional ones, this may be a problem. In C, C++, Go and Pascal, it can happen with pointers, in Prolog with inadvertent unification and in Java it works the same as in Python.

Comment: Keeping track of the refcount is how garbage collection (reclaiming of memory) works in some languages.

Comment: So it saves memory then. Okay. Are there any benefits having to do with how user defined objects interact?

Comment: @PyRulez: it's mostly about saving space, but you can exploit this behavior in some classes/data structures. E.g. a list of `Player` objects may share a single `Board`, that you can then use as a communications device. Don't try to be too smart about this, though, as it is indeed a potential source of bugs.